# Identifying bug in linux kernel module

Tags: multithreading, debugging, linux-kernel, synchronization

I am marking Michael's as he was the first. Thank you to osgx and employee of the month for additional information and assistance.

I am attempting to identify a bug in a consumer/produce kernel module. This is a problem being given to me for a course in university. My teaching assistant was not able to figure it out, and my professor said it was okay if I uploaded online (**he doesn't think Stack can figure it out**!).

- I have included the module, the makefile, and the Kbuild.
- Running the program does not guarantee the bug will present itself.
- I thought the issue was on line 30 since it is possible for a thread to rush to line 36, and starve the other threads. My professor said that is not what he is looking for.
- Unrelated question: What is the purpose of line 40? It seems out of place to me, but my professor said it serves a purporse.
- My professor said the bug is very subtle. The bug is not deadlock.
- My approach was to identify critical sections and shared variables, but I'm stumped. I am not familiar with tracing (as a method of debugging), and was told that while it may help it is not necessary to identify the issue.

File: final.c

```
#include <linux/completion.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static int actor_kthread(void *);
static int writer_kthread(void *);

static DECLARE_COMPLETION(episode_cv);
static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(lock);
static int episodes_written;
static const int MAX_EPISODES = 21;
static bool show_over;
static struct task_info {
    struct task_struct *task;
    const char *name;
    int (*threadfn) (void *);
} task_info[] = {
    {.name = "Liz", .threadfn = writer_kthread},
    {.name = "Tracy", .threadfn = actor_kthread},
    {.name = "Jenna", .threadfn = actor_kthread},
    {.name = "Josh", .threadfn = actor_kthread},
};

static int actor_kthread(void *data) {
    struct task_info *actor_info = (struct task_info *)data;
    spin_lock(&lock);
    while (!show_over) {
        spin_unlock(&lock);
        wait_for_completion_interruptible(&episode_cv); //Line 30
        spin_lock(&lock);
        while (episodes_written) {
            pr_info("%s is in a skit\n", actor_info->name);
            episodes_written--;
        }
        reinit_completion(&episode_cv); // Line 36
    }

    pr_info("%s is done for the season\n", actor_info->name);
    complete(&episode_cv); //Why do we need this line?
    actor_info->task = NULL;
    spin_unlock(&lock);
    return 0;
}

static int writer_kthread(void *data) {
    struct task_info *writer_info = (struct task_info *)data;
    size_t ep_num;

    spin_lock(&lock);
    for (ep_num = 0; ep_num < MAX_EPISODES && !show_over; ep_num++) {
        spin_unlock(&lock);

        /* spend some time writing the next episode */
        schedule_timeout_interruptible(2 * HZ);

        spin_lock(&lock);
        episodes_written++;
        complete_all(&episode_cv);
    }

    pr_info("%s wrote the last episode for the season\n", writer_info->name);
    show_over = true;
    complete_all(&episode_cv);
    writer_info->task = NULL;
    spin_unlock(&lock);
    return 0;
}

static int __init tgs_init(void) {
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(task_info); i++) {
        struct task_info *info = &task_info[i];
        info->task = kthread_run(info->threadfn, info, info->name);
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit tgs_exit(void) {
    size_t i;
    spin_lock(&lock);
    show_over = true;
    spin_unlock(&lock);
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(task_info); i++)
        if (task_info[i].task)
            kthread_stop(task_info[i].task);
}

module_init(tgs_init);
module_exit(tgs_exit);
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("CS421 Final");
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

File: kbuild

```
Kobj-m := final.o
```

File: Makefile

```
# Basic Makefile to pull in kernel's KBuild to build an out-of-tree
# kernel module

KDIR ?= /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build

all: modules

clean modules:
```

Comment: Author of the module has no checked contemporary version of the documentation of completions: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/completion.txt  - Is it safe or not? Where? - somewhere near word bug probably. near any of three.

Comment: @osgx Thank you for your reply, but I'm not sure I understand what you are going at. Are you telling me to look at the bug cases described in the link you posted? If so, I don't see how any of those cases are apparent in this module.

Comment: The hint I got was to pay attention to the completion variable and the lock usage. I don't think the other variables are problematic as shared variables are protected.

Comment: Hmm, past year lections https://www.csee.umbc.edu/~jtang/archives/cs421.s16/lectures/L20KernelSynchronizations.pdf#page=14 has exact same wait/reinit_completion sequence in slide 14... I recommend tracing with lttng (but ftrace with kernelshark https://lwn.net/Articles/425583/ will work too).

Comment: Just idea: writer "Liz" does complete_all; all actors are woken in some time and ... now we may have up to 4 threads (all actors and writer; for example in busy system) to take the spinlock and do their critical section **in no particular order**. Usually (free system, long wait by Liz) three actors will act by turn: Tracy/Jenna/Josh or Josh/Jenna/Tracy, etc; but Liz may wake before some of three did the work. With lower timeout for episode writing I already have "Liz wrote the last episode" and later "Jenna is in a skit". Can complete_all be lost (overwritten by later reinit) in some cases?

Comment: Rey, is there any textual description of the "final"? What should it do, what are requirements?

Comment: @osgx The writer should produce episodes (shared resource) that the actors (consumer thread) will consume. It is acceptable if one of the consumer threads consumes all the resource. For example, it's okay if Tracy is in a skit appears 21 times. As for your first comment, I am still processing it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144519/discussion-on-question-by-rey-identifying-bug-in-linux-kernel-module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When cleaning up in `tgs_exit()` the function executes the following without holding the spinlock:

```
    if (task_info[i].task)
        kthread_stop(task_info[i].task);
```

It's possible for a thread that's ending to set it's `task_info[i].task` to NULL between the check and call to `kthread_stop()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Michael. What are the repercussions of that? I think it means you would have a stray thread that has not been terminated or reaped. Were you able to figure that out by looking at the code, or did you use a tracing tool?

Comment: @MichaelBurr, it is just theory (still may be implemented in some rare cases, for example with outdated/strange register-less machine or brain-less compiler). In practice (amd64, recent gcc) the source was compiled to: `28: mov 0xsome_data(%rbx), %rdi /* load task_info[i].task */; test %rdi,%rdi; /* ==0 ? */; je 39; /*jump over 1 next instr */; callq kthread_stop; 39: add $0x18,%rbx; cmp $0x60,%rbx; jne 28` (no reload from mem between cmp and call). @Rey, it was done without tracing. And it is unsafe to call kthread_stop with NULL argument,  get_task_struct() will try some fields of this NULL.

Comment: Actualy, gcc did two loads from memory with `-O0` (added `obj-m := final.o` and `ccflags-y := -O0` into Makefile. Probably, this is at least one bug of the example.

Comment: @osgx I was able to understood a good portion of the assembled instructions, but I didn't understand your respond message about the two loads from memory? What is the issue with the two loads of memory, and is in happening in the location that MichaelBurr described? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: @Rey, in the Michael's code fragment there are two expressions of `task_info[i].task`. Compiler may read the 'task' field once or twice. With (default) -O2 my gcc did only single read with `mov ..() -> %rdi` (then used rdi to test for zero to implement `if` statement, and also passed rdi as argument into kthread_stop. But when I recompiled with -O0 (try it too with `ccflags-y := -O0` and disassemble with `objdump -d -r final.ko`) I have two reads `mov data20(%rax) -> %rax` - first for `if` and similar second mov to call stop. This shared variable can be changed to NULL by Josh after first read

Comment: Follow up: I was told that this answer is close, but what he was looking for was a thread could potentially be killed twice resulting in a kernel panic.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite confused here.

You claim this is a question from an upcoming exam and it was released by the person delivering the course. Why would they do that? Then you say that TA failed to solve the problem. If TA can't do it, who can expect students to pass?

> (professor) doesn't think Stack can figure it out

If the claim is that the level on this website is bad I definitely agree. But still, claiming it is below a level to be expected from a random university is a stretch. If there is no claim of the sort, I once more ask how are students expected to do it. What if the problem gets solved?

The code itself is imho unsuitable for teaching as it deviates too much from common idioms.

Another answer here noted one side effect of the actual problem. Namely, it was stated that the loop in tgs_exit can race with threads exiting on their own and test the ->task pointer to be non-NULL, while it becomes NULL just afterwards. The discussion whether this can result in a kthread_stop(NULL) call is not really relevant.

Either a kernel thread exiting on its own will clear everything up OR kthread_stop (and maybe something else) is necessary to do it.

If the former is true, the code suffers from a possible use-after-free. After tgs_exit tests that the pointer, the target thread could have exited. Maybe prior to kthread_stop call or maybe just as it was executed. Either way, it is possible that the passed pointer is stale as the area was already freed by the thread which was exiting.

If the latter is true, the code suffers from resource leaks due to insufficient cleanup - there are no kthread_stop calls if tgs_exit is executed after all threads exit.

The kthread_* api allows threads to just exit, hence effects are as described in the first variant.

For the sake of argument let's say the code is compiled in into the kernel (as opposed to being loaded as a module). Say the exit func is called on shutdown.

There is a design problem that there are 2 exit mechanisms and it transforms into a bug as they are not coordinated. A possible solution for this case would set a flag for writers to stop and would wait for a writer counter to drop to 0.

The fact that the code is in a module makes the problem more acute: unless you kthread_stop, you can't tell if the target thread is gone. In particular "actor" threads do:

```
actor_info->task = NULL;
```

So the thread is skipped in the exit handler, which can now finish and let the kernel unload the module itself...

```
spin_unlock(&lock);
return 0;
```

... but this code (located in the module!) possibly was not executed yet.

This would not have happened if the code followed an idiom if always using kthread_stop.

Other issue is that writers wake *everyone* up (so-called "thundering herd problem"), as opposed to at most one actor.

Perhaps the bug one is supposed to find is that each episode has at most one actor? Maybe that the module can exit when there are episodes written but not acted out yet?

The code is extremely weird and if you were shown a reasonable implementation of a thread-safe queue in userspace, you should see how what's presented here does not fit. For instance, why does it block instantly without checking for episodes?

Also a fun fact that locking around the write to show_over plays no role in correctness.

There are more issues and it is quite likely I missed some. As it is, I think the question is of poor quality. It does not look like anything real-world.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to give me such a detailed reply. My exam is in a few hours. After that, I will give you a proper reply.

Comment: Back from the exam. We were given a hint on the exam. We were told there was an issue in tgs_exit and were asked to describe the issue and what consequences it would have. I think I was aptly prepared thanks to the great answers the community provided. We weren’t asked to identify all the issues in the code.

I will answer some of the questions you posed, and avoid some (as I can’t speak for my instructor).

1/6 of the exam pertains to the code. We are given the code early as an opportunity to review it. Then during the exam there are some questions about specific lines in the code.

Comment: I do not think the thundering herd problem was what he was looking for. Also the intent of the program was that each episode could only have one actor.

Comment: Follow up: I was told that this answer is close, but what he was looking for was a thread could potentially be killed twice resulting in a kernel panic. @employee of the month

Comment: That's the use-after-free problem I mentioned.